# nginx, serve static files with authentication

Tags: nginx, aiohttp

I'm developping a web application with [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io) where users authentication is implemented with [aiohttp-security](https://aiohttp-security.readthedocs.io). I use [nginx](https://nginx.org/) for the server deployement. The configuration is inspired by the [aiohttp doc](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/deployment.html#nginx-configuration) and looks like:

```
location /api {
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/api;
}
```

A part of the web application is something like a photo album. I want the photos to be served by ngninx for performance. My configuration looks like for now, it works but bypass the authentication:

```
location /photos {
  root /srv/web/photos/;
  try_files $uri =404;
}
```

How can I make `nginx` serve the photos only to authenticated users? (the authentication mecanism being implemented by the python application, as describe above)

Comment: Just found https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/ (don't know I why missed it before)

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved by using Authentication based on sub-request results.

static/media location can be protected with help of [subrequest authentication](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/).

Considering static/media location: `/media/`

**nginx.conf**

```
....

location /media {
  auth_request /auth;
  #...
}

location = /auth {
    internal;
    proxy_pass              https://yourauthserver/is_authenticated;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    #...
}
...
```

`/is_authenticated` This is the location where your web application check if user is authenticated or not.

Static/Media will be served only if `is_authenticated` returns status code `200`.